# Checking multiple validations using if statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, if-statement

I'm trying to work on **ForgotPassword** section, not in advance but normally by checking conditions. Here trying to check if the user input values Username, Mail Id, Usertype are correct otherwise, show error messages such as `username or mailid or type doesn't match`. But here am failing to show error messages such that the else part isn't working.

> **controller**

```
public ActionResult Forgotpassword1( FormCollection collection)
        {
                string username = collection["username"];
                string mail = collection["mail"];
                string type = collection["type"].ToString();
                Random rand = new Random();
                var password = rand.Next().ToString();
                var getrandomkey = password.Substring(0, 5);
                var lgn = db.tb_log.Where(ob => (ob.username == username) && (ob.usertype == type)).FirstOrDefault();
                string userid = lgn.username;
                if (lgn != null)
                {
                    if (lgn.usertype == ("User"))
                {
                    Session["username"] = lgn.username;
                    Session["type"] = lgn.usertype;
                    userid = lgn.username;
                    var useraccount = db.tb_reg.Where(i => i.gmail == mail && i.usertype == type && i.username == username).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (useraccount != null)
                    {
                        tb_log login = db.tb_log.Where(i => i.username == username && i.usertype == type).FirstOrDefault();
                        if (login != null)
                        {
                         login.code = getrandomkey;
                            db.tb_log.Add(login);
                            int i = db.SaveChanges();
                            if (i > 0)
                            {
                                ViewBag.s = "Verification Code has been send to your registered mail id";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ViewBag.f = "Something went wrong";
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ViewBag.f = "Username or type not match";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ViewBag.f = "Username or Mail not match";
                    }}
```

Comment: What are tb_reg and tb_log exactly? What are the actual values of username and type and did you check that that record exists (no extra spaces for instance)? What is the exact value of lgn.usertype (note that the database probably uses a case-insensitive equality check, but C# is case sensitive) Do note that that "login" value should be identical to the "lgn" you already got

Comment: @HansKeﬆing `tb_reg` holds `mailid` and `tb_log` holds `username` and `userype`(Agent or User), why the else part not working? so that it doesn't check respective fields